# Deserialize Json With Different Class Names C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a web service which I get a complex Json object, everything is fine, but there is a class in this object that changes its name in each response according on Item name, this prevents the normal deserialization process

```
public class Threads
{
    public object threads { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public Async async { get; set; }
    public Products products { get; set; } => Products Class
}


public class Products
{
    //public DR7614060 dr7614060 { get; set; }
    
    // I try to Deserialize the class as  Dictionary but nothing happend
    Dictionary<string, DR7614060> Pairs { get ; set; }
}


public class DR7614060
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string threadId { get; set; }
    public string productId { get; set; }
    public bool mainColor { get; set; }
    public Productrollup productRollup { get; set; }
}
```

Json :

https://github.com/Kremed/ContenPageFlowDirection/blob/master/Json.json

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json as well?

Comment: a) please provide a json example showing how exactly it looks like for two different classes; b) please mention which Json lib you are using (STJ?); c) please describe the error "nothing happend" is not a valid description. d) please describe the expected behavior. All this would really help to provide a useful answer.

Comment: Json Data : 

https://github.com/Kremed/ContenPageFlowDirection/blob/master/Json.json

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this configuration to work:

```
public class Threads
{
    [JsonProperty("threads")]
    public object ThreadsThreads { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public object Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("async")]
    public ThreadsAsync Async { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public Dictionary<string, StupidClassName> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I think you were on the right track, you just need to move the dictionary up one level to allow for the key value pair to be based on the name of the class. So that leaves the `DR7614060` definition.  Just give it a proper class name to use for deserialization. Now your `Products` dictionary will have key = 'given class name' value = 'deserialized object with defined class name'

```
public partial class StupidClassName // instead of DMxxxxxx
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("threadId")]
    public Guid ThreadId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productId")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mainColor")]
    public bool MainColor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productRollup")]
    public ProductRollup ProductRollup { get; set; }
    // .... more props etc.
 }
```

From the Json you posted I got:

[image]